# Programmatically create a calendar with Graph API and Office365

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I want to synchronize a list of appointments from an php backend to an organize-wide calendar in Office365.
I didn't find any possibility to create a calendar as an app and not using and service-user as owner.

Answer (score 0):

There is no notion of a organization wide calendar. You can create an Office 365 Group which will have a shared calendar and then make everyone in the organization a member of that group.